# How can I reopen it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises, specific-question, reopen

[What will be final velocity of three charges $q$, $q$, $2q$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233232/)

How can I reopen it? All concepts come out from questions. If I know how to solve it, I would know concept automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking how to solve problems like that is not on topic here. If you want the question reopened, you'll need to make it ask something else. Identify the specific issue that is blocking you from getting to the solution, and ask about that.

Comment: I am not getting what to ask. I am asking concept of how is question solved.

Comment: How the question is solved is the sort of thing we explicitly mean to exclude by saying "conceptual".

Comment: sorry for my poor English. but I did not understand your comment

Comment: OK I will remove this line. Would it work then?

Comment: What I was saying in my last comment was that this is not a conceptual question. "How to solve this question" is not a concept. The whole reason we use the word "conceptual" is to show that asking how to solve the question is off topic. It will take more than removing a line to make the question on topic; you'll need to add some text to focus on the specific issue that is giving you trouble.